# Power Query Code to filter a Column that begins with an alphabet

Tags: powerquery

How can I write a Power Query Code that can filter any column that begins with a number? I want to leave only columns that start with a number.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
columns=List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform (Table.ColumnNames(Source), each if List.ContainsAny({Text.Start(_,1)},{"0".."9"}) then _ else null)),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,columns)
in #"Removed Other Columns"
```

or

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
columns=List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform (Table.ColumnNames(Source), each if  Character.ToNumber(Text.Start(_,1))<=57 and  Character.ToNumber(Text.Start(_,1))>=48 then _ else null)),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,columns)
in #"Removed Other Columns"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
columns=List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform (Table.ColumnNames(Source), each if Text.Length(Text.Select(Text.Start(_,1), {"0".."9"})) =1 then _ else null)),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,columns)
in #"Removed Other Columns"
```

or bunches of other ways that work on the results from Table.ColumnNames()